# Just a regular block reuse with Twig - how to?

Tags: twig

Imagine we have a block template which we want to use many times on a page. And every time we need to do three things:

- set a class on the top level
- set a title
- add some content

How to achieve this on Twig?

I know about macro, but it doesn't take content.
I know about block, but it doesn't take parameters.

So... how to do this in a normal way?

Since I don't know how, I'll use an imaginary constructs 'blockdef' and 'blockuse' later on to demonstrate the task (which is absolutely ordinary).

So let's say we have this cute Twig block template:

**blocks.twig:**

```html
{% blockdef myblock(class, title) %}
<div class="block {{class}}">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="content">{{content}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endgoodblock %}
```

And want to use it like this:

**main.twig:**

```html
{% blockuse myblock('c1', 'Title1' %}
  <p>Block 1 content</p>
{% endblockuse %}

{% blockuse myblock('c2', 'Title2' %}
  <p>Block 2 content</p>
{% endblockuse %}

{% blockuse myblock('c3', 'Title3' %}
  <p>Block 3 content</p>
{% endblockuse %}
```

Is there anything like this?

UPDATE. For example, this is how it's solved on **Jade**:

```
mixin myblock(cls, title)
  .block(class=cls)
    .inner
      .title= title
      .content
        block

+myblock('c1', 'Title1')
  p Block 1 content

+myblock('c2', 'Title2')
  p Block 2 content

+myblock('c3', 'Title3')
  p Block 3 content
```

Comment: You could create your own `node` extend it from `block` and add parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could use `include with`:

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'class': 'class', 'title': 'title', 'content: 'content'} %}
```

Comment: content is not a string, it's a another part of template. Could you please elaborate how the full solution would look like?

Comment: Then you can either include it from template.html or set it to a variable and pass that variable as `'content': variable`.

Comment: Marc, the problem with content here is that it's not a string, but template. So you  need to render it first, declaring a new capture variable and then pass it to a macro (more becoming than `include with`). Honeslty it doesn't look reasonable or optimal.